# Зажатие кнопки Ctrl, кнопка q должна зажиматься и отжиматься, а потом сама кнопка Ctrl должна будет отжата

Tags: autohotkey

Можно ли написать такой код, чтобы кнопка Ctrl была зажата, а кнопка q зажималась и отжималась, а потом чтоб была отжата сама кнопка ctrl?
Я написал Код, но ctrl кнопка не отжата, и приходится на клавиатуре нажимать на неё самому.

Comment: Со стороны звучит про100 дико. Как программно сделать чтоб у меня физически прилипла кнопка. :)

Comment: Да, это ahk, просто первый раз на вашем сайте, не понял что нужно именно писать)

Comment: А можно обнародовать код? А то с объяснения не понятно, чего вы хотите добиться...